# Automate migration of stored procedures from SQL Server to Postgres

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, database-migration

We are having around 75~ table and 100~ stored procedures. We have created a custom NodeJS app with Sequelize to migrate the tables and its data. But we wanted to migrate the stored procedures too.

The only possible options that we do have is, is to manually convert every stored procedure.

Manually converting each stored procedure is a tedious task. So is there any way other than manually converting the code? I hope someone can guide/help me with this.

FYI:

- SQL Server version: 16+
- Postgres version: 12+

Comment: The concepts between T-SQL and PL/pgSQL are fundamentally different. I really doubt there is a any halfway decent automatic migration possible. Doing it manually after understanding all the differences and learning the best practices and approaches in Postgres (and PL/pgSQL) is the best way to do this migration.

Comment: There are a lot of data management and migration tools. Sequelize isn't one of them. It's not even a data management tool, it's an ORM mean to handle objects and object graphs. There are no objects in data management jobs, except Table, Row,  Field, and transformations. You can't just move from one database to another, especially not when using the wrong tool

Comment: Check https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Converting_from_other_Databases_to_PostgreSQL#Microsoft_SQL_Server

Answer (score 1):

There soon will be, Amazon is launching an open-source tool under Apache to act as a translation layer between traditional SQL applications and a Postgres database. This translation layer allows your code to operate under its current SQL setup, but it gets translated for the Postgres DB. It's called Babelfish for Postgresql. It's slated for 2021, but it is not currently available. https://babelfish-for-postgresql.github.io/babelfish-for-postgresql/

Comment: Babelfish for PostgreSQL is available now. To understand what SQL syntax and functions are supported, see: https://babelfishpg.org/docs/usage/limitations-of-babelfish

John Russell, developer advocate for Aurora PostgreSQL and Babelfish for PostgreSQL

Comment: The question is about automatic conversion from Sybase stored procedures to basic sql to use via postgres

Answer (score -2):

There is absolutely no possibilities to automatically convert Transact SQL procedures to PG PL/SQL functions because of many lack of functionalities :

1. PG does not do pessimistic lock that SQL Server uses by default
2. PG do not support nested transaction that SQL Server support. In
   this case the behaviour will be different and the results not the
   same.
3. String data have collations CI/AS by default in SQL Server that PG
   do not support completly (ICU collations are not supported for LIKE
   and raise an error as an example).
4. PG does not conform to the SQL Standard regarding the string
   datatype. PG use only CHAR/VARCHAR. No NCHAR/NVARCHAR, but strinsg
   in PG are NCCHAR/NVARCHAR
5. PG support function overloading that is not supported in SQL Server.
   The function using a generic code with the sql_variant datatype must
   be translated into function overloading
6. PG does not make differnces between function and procedure (which is
   a lack of security). SQL Server does it...

There will be many other functionalities that is completly different, and I am writing a series of papers about the differences between PG and SQL Server. [The first one is about performances of DBA queries](http://mssqlserver.fr/postgresql-vs-microsoft-sql-server-comparison-part-1-count-and-dba-command-performances/), the secound about COUT performances and the third a complete panorama of functional differences...

Comment: 6. is wrong. There is a difference between a function and a procedure in Postgres (and a much bigger one than in SQL Server, as procedures aren't meant to return data)

Comment: Regarding your blog series: nobody will believe you know PostgreSQL if you don't even [write the name correctly](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/the-shibboleth-of-postgresql/)

Comment: In the SQL standard (ISO) a function is not allowed to modify the database in any way (no INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, MERGE, TRUNCATE of tables or views and no DDL, no DCL). It is why I say that PG make no differences between those to concepts...

Comment: Can you tell me in which chapter in the SQL standard it is documented that functions aren't allowed to use DML? It's the first time I hear of this restriction. Chapter "4.27.4 Routine descriptors" even allows a descriptor to indicate if the a routine (=function or procedure) is a "mutator" routine

Comment: Please refer to the ISO document and post its references.

Comment: ISO/IEC 9075-2 Chapter "4.27.4 Routine descriptors". And please tell me the ISO document and chapter where _you_ found the claim that functions aren't allowed to run DML statements

Comment: No mater what the SQL standard allows you to do, both SQL Server and PostgreSQL allow you to create functions to execute INSERT, UPDATE, etc. statements. So who cares what the standard says? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @Frank_Heikens no Franck, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, MERGE, TRUNCATE, CREATE, DROP, GRANT... are not allowed in data tables nor views for UDF. It is only allowed for table variable, whatever is the UDF (scalar, inline table or multistatement table). That database is not allowed to be modify in anykind when using a UDF... This is by security !

Comment: @SQLpro: The manual clearly shows me an example using an INSERT and it's also using a CREATE FUNCTION statement: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15#c-creating-a-multi-statement-table-valued-function And I repeat, who cares?

Comment: @Frank_Heikens As I said, the INSERT is inserting rows in a variable table that is not persitant and does not exists in the database. This is a table variable which is equivalent as an array and will exists only in the execution of the UDF and scoped only by the UDF code... So the database is not modified at all !

Comment: @SQLpro: I see. But I see that as a limitation of SQL Server, not something good (nor bad) from PostgreSQL or any other database. And who knows what Microsoft will implement in a next version?

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name ISO 9075-2 of 2007-12-17 defines that (7.13 - item 26) "A <query expression> QE shall not generally contain a <routine invocation> whose subject routine is an SQL-invoked routine that possibly modifies SQL-data." Same terms in DELETE (14.9), MERGE (14.12) and UPDATE (14.14) and also for CASE statement (6.11)... You can only put FUNCTIONS in statement nor PROCEDURE. So functionnaly function cannot use writable SQL commands... CQFD !